# Syntax error with Python one-liner

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax

```
python -c 'import sys; print "a"'
```

works, and

```
python -c 'for a in [1, 2, 3]: print a'
```

works, but

```
python -c 'import sys; for a in [1, 2, 3]: print a'
```

fails with

```
File "<string>", line 1
  import sys; for a in [1, 2, 3]: print a
                ^
```

Why?

---

**EDIT** My workaround:

```
python -c 'import sys; print "\n".join([1, 2, 3])'
```

(Luckily it worked for my real code too.)

Comment: What OS and what shell are you using?

Comment: I can reproduce it ubuntu+bash, python 2.7.3.

Comment: It's not connected to the shell or the `-c` flag; the same thing happens in the REPL.

Comment: You're missing a line in the error message: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Another workaround for Python 3, use a comprehension: `python -c 'import sys; [print(i) for i in [1, 2, 3]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use `;` to separate non-compound statements on a single line; the grammar makes no allowance for a non-compound statement and a compound statement separated by a semicolon.

The relevant grammar rules are as follows:

```
stmt: simple_stmt | compound_stmt
simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE
```

The `;` in the `simple_stmt` production is the only place where semicolons are allowed to separate statements. For further details, see the [full Python grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html).

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer to your exact question, but still may help someone.
You can actually split the command line in shell.

**sh/bash/etc:**

```
python -c 'import sys
for a in [1, 2, 3]: print a'
```

**Windows cmd** (`C:\>` and `'More?'` are cmd prompts, don't enter those):

```
C:\>python -c import sys^
More?
More? for a in [1, 2, 3]: print a
```

Added in 2021:
For some reason the cmd version above does not work on my current Windows 10 environment. Seems like w/o quotes Python interpreter truncates the command at first space. This variant still works:

```
C:\>python -c ^
More? "import sys^
More? 
More? for a in [1, 2, 3]: print a
```

Please note, that you need to press ENTER immediately after the caret (^) symbol. Also please note the double quote on the first continuation line in the last example.